# Primepush + Wildfly not work. Atmosphere can not find annotated classes

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, wildfly, primepush

I'm using next configuration:

1. Application Server - Wildfly 9.0
2. Primefaces 5.1 RC1, Atmosphere 2.2.2 - added as modules (all dependencies were added).
   I've stopped on this configuration, because any other is falling down with heap of errors.

I'm going to use primepush, I've done all as in example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/notify.xhtml, but it does not work for me.

My part of web.xml for primepush conf:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have in my project class annotated with @PushEndpoint, in xhtml file I have socket connected to the same channel. After deploying I don't have any errors, but there is a strange string in the first line

```
21:25:24,433 ERROR [org.primefaces.push.PushServlet] (MSC service thread 1-8) No Annotated class     using @PushEndpoint found. Push will not work.
21:25:24,433 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /oasa
21:25:24,556 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0016: Replaced deployment "oasa.war" with deployment "oasa.war"
21:25:24,701 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (Thread-150) Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.2.4
```

After googling I found solution to add to my web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.annotation.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>org.primefaces.push</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>MY_PACKAGE_WITH_PUSH_ENDPOINTS</param-value>
</init-param>
```

All is deploying fine, but when I send message using

```
EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus().publish(MY_CHANNEL, MY_VARIABLE);
```

Here is what I've gotten on wildfly console :

```
22:02:54,284 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-19) UT005023: Exception handling request to /MY_PROJECT/primepush/MY_CHANNEL: org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for /MY_PROJECT/primepush/MY_CHANNEL
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.map(AsynchronousProcessor.java:355)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:154)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:104)
at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:66)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2063)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:211)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:197)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:259) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:246) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:75) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:165) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:737) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

22:02:55,634 WARN  [org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor] (default task-20) Failed invoking AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(): org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for http://localhost:8080/MY_PROJECT/primepush/MY_CHANNEL
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.map(AsynchronousProcessor.java:355)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:154)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:104)
at org.atmosphere.container.Servlet30CometSupport.service(Servlet30CometSupport.java:66)
at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2063)
at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.dispatch(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:568)
at org.atmosphere.websocket.DefaultWebSocketProcessor.open(DefaultWebSocketProcessor.java:213)
at org.atmosphere.container.JSR356Endpoint.onOpen(JSR356Endpoint.java:192)
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.EndpointSessionHandler.onConnect(EndpointSessionHandler.java:84) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter$1.handleUpgrade(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:121) [undertow-websockets-jsr-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.exchangeComplete(HttpReadListener.java:285) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpServerConnection.exchangeComplete(HttpServerConnection.java:212) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.invokeExchangeCompleteListeners(HttpServerExchange.java:1141) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange.terminateResponse(HttpServerExchange.java:1361) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.terminateResponse(Connectors.java:98) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.ServerFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.channelFinished(ServerFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:51) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.exitFlush(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:300) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.conduits.AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.flush(AbstractFixedLengthStreamSinkConduit.java:234) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at org.xnio.conduits.ConduitStreamSinkChannel.flush(ConduitStreamSinkChannel.java:162)
at io.undertow.channels.DetachableStreamSinkChannel.flush(DetachableStreamSinkChannel.java:118) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at org.xnio.channels.Channels.flushBlocking(Channels.java:63)
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletOutputStreamImpl.close(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:607) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.closeStreamAndWriter(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:483) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:566) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:307) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:246) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:75) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:165) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:737) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Beta7.jar:1.1.0.Beta7]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_67]

22:02:55,649 WARN  [org.atmosphere.websocket.protocol.SimpleHttpProtocol] (default task-20) org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereMappingException: No AtmosphereHandler maps request for http://localhost:8080/MY_PROJECT/primepush/MY_CHANNEL. Unable to deliver the websocket messages to installed component. Status 500 Message Server Error
```

In any case websockets is not working for me...

Please, advise how to fix that.

P.S. I've just repeated all steps on wildfly 8.1 Final. I have the same picture - all errors as in the wildfly 9.0 case....

P.P.S.
module.xml

atmosphere

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.atmosphere">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="atmosphere-runtime-2.2.2.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
       <module name="javax.servlet.api"/>
       <module name="javax.websocket.api" export="true"/>
       <module name="org.slf4j" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

primefaces

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.primefaces" slot="5">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="primefaces-5.1.RC1.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.annotation.api"/>
        <module name="javax.faces.api"/>
        <module name="org.apache.commons.fileupload"/>
        <module name="org.atmosphere"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Comment: Did you generate and attach janex indexes for the modules you created?

Comment: In the newest versions of Jboss (since wildfly 8.0), it seems, it does not generate. But I can show module.xml files of my modules.

Comment: You need to manually generate and attach janex indexes to your custom modules that have annotations.